# Datatables target except the first column

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

Any idea how to use `columnDefs` property like below

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
    columnDefs: [
        { targets: [> 0], visible: true}
    ]
} );
```

Can I do that?

I need to target all columns except first column.

Comment: Do you mean *except* the first column? E.g., you want it to apply to all of them *other than* the first?

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets)? It doesn't show any way to do that without using a class on all of the columns you want to target.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, thats i want it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So wich mean i cant do that?? if i'm use specfication, i cant, cause my column always change. Wich mean i have filter date range, so my coulmn based on that date, if i'm pick Januray until May, so i have  4 column, Buyer, January, Ferbuary and May. tahts why i cant use target for spesifict

Comment: If you have 5 columns `targets: [1,2,3,4]`

Answer (score 6):

Take a look on [the documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) .

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
    columnDefs: [
        { targets: [0], visible: false},
        { targets: '_all', visible: true}
    ]
} );
```

The first column will be hidden in the table while all others will be visible.